# -Property time / Not showing time. PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a quick question about powershell. If I write `$event1 = Get-EventLog system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6006} | Select-Object -first 1 -Property Index` it only displays the index. Which is right... But if I write `$event1 = Get-EventLog system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6006} | Select-Object -first 1 -Property Time` The time is not showing up... Just a blank row. What am I doing wrong. I fond nothing on the internet about that probem. So maybe you could help me. I am a beginner btw :)

Comment: That property does not exist. Use either `TimeGenerated` or `TimeWritten`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, there is no property called `Time`.  Use `TimeGenerated` or `TimeWritten` instead.

```
$event1 = Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6006} | Select-Object -First 1 -Property TimeGenerated
```

However, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog) say that
*"Get-EventLog uses a Win32 API that is deprecated. The results may not be accurate. Use the Get-WinEvent cmdlet instead."*

To change to `Get-WinEvent` the following gets you what you want:

```
$event1 = Get-WinEvent -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 6006} | Select-Object -First 1 -Property TimeCreated
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That solved it. The output now is: "TimeCreated        
-----------        
10.12.2020 07:06:13". Do you know, how I can get rid of the "TimeCreated and the ------" and just have the time as output?

Comment: @Rabbit73 Just change `Select-Object -First 1 -Property TimeCreated` into `Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty TimeCreated`